# How to merge when each row on table A needs multiple rows from table B in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.

InstructorRelated

```
TermCode |Term_Seq_ID |Subject|Course|QuestionNbr|InstructorName |Instructor_Pid|Mean |StdDev
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |5          |SKYWALKER, LUKE|BR549         |4.349|1.033
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |5          |AMIDALA, PADME |39AHW         |4.285|1.030
```

ClassRelated:

```
TermCode |Term_Seq_ID |Subject|Course|QuestionNbr|InstructorName |Instructor_Pid|Mean |StdDev
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |6          |NULL           |ALL           |4.078|1.049
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |9          |NULL           |ALL           |3.806|1.128
```

What the client wants is for these two tables to be merged such that every ACC 201 instructor has a row for questions 5, 6, and 9, like so:

```
TermCode |Term_Seq_ID |Subject|Course|QuestionNbr|InstructorName |Instructor_Pid|Mean |StdDev
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |5          |SKYWALKER, LUKE|BR549         |4.342|1.033
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |6          |NULL           |ALL           |4.078|1.049
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |9          |NULL           |ALL           |3.806|1.128
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |5          |AMIDALA, PADME |39AHW         |4.285|1.030
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |6          |NULL           |ALL           |4.078|1.049
FS15     |1154        |ACC    |201   |9          |NULL           |ALL           |3.806|1.128
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from
(select * from InstructorRelated
Union all
select * from ClassRelated
Union all
select * from InstructorRelated) x
```

...Not sure why you want the info from classrelated in there twice...if you're looking to replace the NULLs and ALLs with the instructor name, then:

```
select * from (
    select TermCode ,
    Term_Seq_ID ,
    Subject,
    Course,
    QuestionNbr,
    InstructorName ,
    Instructor_Pid,
    Mean ,
    StdDev
    from InstructorRelated
Union
    select CR.TermCode ,
    CR.Term_Seq_ID ,
    CR.Subject,
    CR.Course,
    CR.QuestionNbr,
    IR.InstructorName ,
    IR.Instructor_Pid,
    CR.Mean ,
    CR.StdDev
from InstructorRelated IR
    join ClassRelated CR
    on IR.subject = CR.subject and IR.Course=CR.Course) x
```

Comment: The client wanted it this way for a report.  I'll try out your solution.

Comment: try it now, I changed the union all to a union which should group it

Comment: That did it. Thanks!